# Android calling functions in a shared library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to follow this tutorial
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html
but I'm in eclipse making an android app

So I create blank project and add a new class

```
package com.example.jpgtest;

import android.util.Log;

public class TestJNIPrimitive {
    //static {
          //System.loadLibrary("myjni"); // myjni.dll (Windows) or libmyjni.so (Unixes)
     //     System.load("d:/libjpeg.so");
     //     Log.d("TestJNIPrimitive", "load ok");
     //  }

       // Declare a native method average() that receives two ints and return a double containing the average
       private native double average(int n1, int n2);

       // Test Driver
       public static void main() {
           System.load("d:/libjpeg.so");
           Log.d("TestJNIPrimitive", "load ok");

          double d =  new TestJNIPrimitive().average(3, 2);

          //double d =  new TestJNIPrimitive().average(3, 2);
          Log.d("TestJNIPrimitive", "d="+d);
       }
}
```

and call it from `onCreate()`

```
TestJNIPrimitive t = new TestJNIPrimitive();
        t.main();
```

I made the c and h file like this
TestJNIPrimitive.h
/

```
* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class TestJNIPrimitive */

#ifndef _Included_TestJNIPrimitive
#define _Included_TestJNIPrimitive
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     TestJNIPrimitive
 * Method:    average
 * Signature: (II)D
 */
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_TestJNIPrimitive_average
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

TestJNIPrimitive.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "TestJNIPrimitive.h"

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_TestJNIPrimitive_average(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint n1, jint n2) 
{
   jdouble result;
   //printf("In C, the numbers are %d and %d\n", n1, n2);
   result = ((jdouble)n1 + n2) / 2.0;
   // jint is mapped to int, jdouble is mapped to double
   return result;
}
```

i build it and make a libjpg.so on my d drive root
i check the symbols

```
$ readelf -Ws /cygdrive/d/libjpeg.so | grep average
   272: 00003f5c    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 Java_TestJNIPrimitive_average
  1896: 00003f5c    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 Java_TestJNIPrimitive_average
```

When I run it, the load works ok but the call to average fails with
No implementation found for native Lcom/example/jpegtest/TestJNIPrimative;.average (II)D

Any ideas please, I'm really stuck on this

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the packace into JNI. That's the reason the function is not found.

Your Java package is: com.example.jpgtest

So your Native function must be:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_example_jpgtest_TestJNIPrimitive_average(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint n1, jint n2) 
{
   ...
}
```

After compile with ndk-build, and use your new libjpeg.so must work.

I have to add that your java looks weird (at less to my eyes). I will implement that as:

```
package com.example.jpgtest;

import android.util.Log;

public class TestJNIPrimitive 
{
    // Test Driver
    public static void main()
    {
          Log.d("TestJNIPrimitive", "load ok");

          double d =  new TestJNIPrimitive().average(3, 2);
          Log.d("TestJNIPrimitive", "d="+d);
    }
    // Native functions (Callbacks from Java to C++)
    // =========================================================================
    // Declare a native method average() that receives two ints and return a double containing the average
       private native double average(int n1, int n2);

    // Load Native Libraries
    // =========================================================================
    static 
    {
         System.load("libjpeg.so");
    }
}
```

And the so must be inside folder libs/armeabi-v7a

I you want a basic theory check [this](http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/cs510ajp/) or the [specifications](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~kloukin/IN2P3/material/jni.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

i was unable to figure out the problem, but instead i read this
https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

i build and ran the hello-jni example and then i build a new project and then added in the jni folder from the test and change the package name and the class name to match the new project

then i started modifying the functions to my needs and its ok now

not easy stuff this